# Problem with nodes in TikZ graphs with graphdrawing library over LuaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am trying to refer to nodes set within a graph structure deployed by using the `graphdrawing` library but I don't get the wished for result. This is my MWE, which is compiled over `LuaLaTeX` in order to have the functionality of the library available:

```
%\RequirePackage{luatex85} <- Not really needed, I believe

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
  \usegdlibrary{trees}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[binary tree layout]    
  \graph{a -- b};
  \draw (a) circle[radius=2mm];
  \draw (b) circle[radius=5mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to have a circle centered on each node, but what I get instead is the two circles centered both on node "a". I may be doing something in the wrong way here, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you add the `binary tree layout` option to the \graph instead of the tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
  \usegdlibrary{trees,circular}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[binary tree layout]
  \graph 
  {a -- b};
  \draw (a) circle[radius=2mm];
  \draw (b) circle[radius=5mm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [binary tree layout]
  {a -- b};
  \draw (a) circle[radius=2mm];
  \draw (b) circle[radius=5mm];  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]